# Multiple Rails/Rack apps Nginx one for each subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I just hired a VPS with Ubuntu 12.10 x64. I've managed to get one Rails app running with passenger-nginx. Now I want to run another app as a subdomain, say for example `admin.mydomain.com`. How can I do that, and where do I point my subdomain in DNS records, A/CNAME/MX?

Answer (score 0):

to have a virtualhost-ish server on nginx:

```
server {
    server_name sub.domain.tld;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4001/railsapp;
}
```

name resolution-wise, any CNAME of A records will do just fine.